# Labels coloring

Tags: qgis-2.4

How to apply different color to the fields in the label through SQL query or by some other way . For Ex: I have selected this label query :
coalesce("Err_2013", ' ') || '\n' || coalesce("WP_2013", ' ') || '\n' || coalesce("District_C", ' ')

Here I want to display first field i.e "Err_2013" with red color, second field "WP_2013" with blue color and third field " District_C" with green color.